# Map not showing in this HTML

Tags: html, google-maps

This is my first post. I have created this html but the roadmap is not showing, only the top layer. I want the roadmap to be underneath and showing. Any other ideas/suggestions would be helpful too. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:1000px; height:800px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD09gQTWYW6qTmUUFZhgRZgIYmQerp-    o_8&sensor=true">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    var layer_1;
    var layer_2;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.55, 2.433),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2>>0",
          from: "1LWvucBaQxLRuHB6jM8e-FgK2fXqhJQdK6Wm0IDY"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
      layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2>>0",
          from: "1LWvucBaQxLRuHB6jM8e-FgK2fXqhJQdK6Wm0IDY"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
      layer_2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2>>0",
          from: "1LWvucBaQxLRuHB6jM8e-FgK2fXqhJQdK6Wm0IDY"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is impossible, the map-tiles(which also contain the roadmap) can't be rendered on top of a layer. To achieve it you'll need your own roadmap which will be used as overlay.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.  The code above shows me a road map with the FusionTablesLayer(s) on top of it.  Where you expecting something else?  Are you asking how to make the FusionTablesLayers more transparent?

Comment: Thanks. When I publish it, only the top layer appears. The road map layer is blocked out and the sea is white with black guidelines. So should I add a map layer below the layers in the code, Dr Molle?